# Section numbering with numbering like 1.11

Tags: numbering, counters

How do I set my section numbers like the given format? I'm in need of the format given below.

I'm using `gsm-l.cls`.  I'm just using tags like:

```
\chapter{name}
\section{sectionname}
\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}
```

Example:

Chapter 1
1.1. Section name
Theorem: 1.1.1.
Theorem: 1.1.2.
Remark: 1.1.3.

Comment: Could you please expand your question? What class are you using? How are you defining theorems and remarks?

Comment: Can you point to a link where the class can be examined? However, if you're using it for a submission, don't try changing the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
\documentclass{gsm-l}

% section numbers preceded by chapter number
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}

% define the theorem environments
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] % theorems are numbered by section

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark} % remarks share the theorem counter

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{Section title}
\begin{theorem}
$1+1=2$
\end{theorem}
\begin{remark}
The above theorem is hard.
\end{remark}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the usual recommendation for ams document classes (of which `gsm-l.cls` is one) is to include the command

```
\numberwithin{section}{chapter}
```

in the preamble.

Comment: It doesn't seem necessary for `gsm-l`

Comment: but it *is* necessary, unless you do as you have done in your answer: `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}` -- `\numberwithin` replaces that.